# How to access mongo db data in django project?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I have two db in my django project. Default db mysql and secondary db mongodb.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'xyz',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD':'1234',
    'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
    'PORT':'3306',
},
'mongo_db':
{
    'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'NAME' : 'pets_info'   
}
```

}

how to get data from mongo db in django views.

```
def get_pets(request):
    mongo_cursor = connections['mongo_db'].cursor()
    return HttpResponse("hi")
```

Comment: RTFD - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database

Comment: I am using the same thing. connection establish successfully with the mongo db. I have problem to access data from the db. Could you write down the steps to access data.

Comment: Did you read anything about django at all??? Please read the documentation before asking questions. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I have read about the Django and also developed Django project.

Comment: In this project i am using two db one mysql and secondary mongo. I did not created any model for mongodb. I have data in mongo db and not able to access mongodb when connection information is giving settings file.

Comment: I tried with pymongo and able to access db but i want to access by django teminology

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/